# Smoke Particles and Fluid

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

Taylor Swifts music video has these golden particle/fluid/smoke simulation. It is like a glowing pipe which has particles & smoke or fluid or both coming out randomly. I understand fluid simulation and smoke simulation, but this effect seems to be a mix of those. Any ideas on how to make this effect?

Here are some screenshots from the video:[image: smoke and fluid and particles together]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RsEZmictANA&ab_channel=TaylorSwiftVEVO   here is the video link

Comment: Thats a smoke with very low or negative Heat value, enabled Disolve. Sparks are particles driven by Fluid Flow force field object (with smoke sim domain assigned)... if it still a topic for you or you need more details let me know (to address comment to me use "@vklidu").